# Keras model predict output is an array with values between 0 and 1

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm building an autoencoder network for finding outliers in text.

I first built an numpy array with my input represented as ascii texts, but I can't get them back.

My input looks like this:

```
fab_shadow_black.9.png
fab_shadow_dark.9.png
fab_shadow_light.9.png
fastscroller_handle_normal.xml
fastscroller_handle_pressed.xml
folder_fab.png
ic_account_circle_grey_24dp.xml
ic_action_cancel_light.png
```

My whole code is as follows:

```py
import sys
from keras import Input, Model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy as np
from pprint import pprint
from google.colab import drive

drive.mount('/content/drive')
with open('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/drawables.txt', 'r') as arquivo:
    dados = arquivo.read().splitlines()

def tamanho_maior_elemento(lista):
  maior = 0
  for elemento in lista:
    tamanho_elemento = len(elemento)
    if tamanho_elemento > maior:
      maior = tamanho_elemento
  return maior

def texto_para_ascii(lista, tamanho_maior_elemento):
  lista_ascii = list()
  for elemento in lista:
    elemento_ascii_lista = list()
    elemento_com_zeros = elemento.ljust(tamanho_maior_elemento, "0")
    for caractere in elemento_com_zeros:
      elemento_ascii_lista.append(ord(caractere))
    lista_ascii.append(elemento_ascii_lista)
  return lista_ascii

def ascii_para_texto(lista):
  lista_ascii = list()
  for elemento in lista:
    elemento_ascii_lista = list()
    for caractere in elemento:
      elemento_ascii_lista.append(chr(caractere))
    elemento_ascii_string = "".join(elemento_ascii_lista)
    lista_ascii.append(elemento_ascii_string)
  return lista_ascii

tamanho_maior_elemento = tamanho_maior_elemento(dados)

tamanho_lista = len(dados)

dados_ascii = texto_para_ascii(dados, tamanho_maior_elemento)

np_dados_ascii = np.array(dados_ascii)

tamanho_comprimido = int(tamanho/5)

dados_input = Input(shape=(tamanho_maior_elemento,))

hidden = Dense(tamanho_comprimido, activation='relu')(dados_input)

output = Dense(tamanho_maior_elemento, activation='relu')(hidden)
resultado = Dense(tamanho_maior_elemento, activation='sigmoid')(output)

autoencoder = Model(input=dados_input, output=resultado)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
history = autoencoder.fit(np_dados_ascii, np_dados_ascii, epochs=10)

plt.plot(history.history["loss"])
plt.ylabel("Loss")
plt.xlabel("Epoch")
plt.show()

saida_predict = autoencoder.predict(np_dados_ascii)

saida_lista = saida_predict.tolist()

pprint(saida_predict)
pprint(saida_lista)
```

My input is a numpy array with each string represented as ascii number right-padded by zeroes.

The problem is that the output from predict is a lot of values between zero and one that I can't convert back to text.

```
array([[1.        , 0.9999999 , 1.        , ..., 1.        , 1.        ,
        1.        ],
       [0.99992466, 1.        , 1.        , ..., 1.        , 1.        ,
        1.        ],
       [1.        , 0.99999994, 1.        , ..., 1.        , 1.        ,
        1.        ],
       ...,
       [0.9999998 , 0.9999999 , 1.        , ..., 1.        , 1.        ,
        0.9999999 ],
       [1.        , 0.9999998 , 1.        , ..., 1.        , 1.        ,
        1.        ],
       [0.9999999 , 0.99999994, 1.        , ..., 1.        , 1.        ,
        1.        ]], dtype=float32)
```

I should be getting an array containing the ascii numbers just like I put in the input, what am I getting wrong?

Comment: In your code `resultado = Dense(tamanho_maior_elemento, activation='sigmoid')(output)` you have used sigmoid activation that's why you have prediction in range 0 to 1. Try to change it with linear activation.

Comment: @kruxx I couldn't find what should I put inside activation="" to use the linear activation, what should I put in it?

Comment: You have no need to assign anything in activation because [here](https://keras.io/layers/core/), it mentioned that default it is linear activation.

Comment: @kruxx worked! if you submit as an answer I will mark as correct. But now I don't know how to interpret the results this function is giving me. I've asked another question about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55794234/unsure-about-the-result-my-autoencoder-neural-network-is-giving-me-from-keras-pr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code,

```
resultado = Dense(tamanho_maior_elemento, activation='sigmoid')(output)
```

You have used sigmoid activation that's why you have prediction in range 0 to 1. Try to change it with linear activation.

```
resultado = Dense(tamanho_maior_elemento)(output)
```

And for linear activation, you have no need to assign anything in activation because [here](https://keras.io/layers/core/), it mentioned that default it is linear activation.